# 複数人で操作するディレクトリやファイルのパーミッションについて

Tags: sftp

sftpでサーバー上のファイルを同時編集する環境があります。

sftpユーザーは接続する人の数だけあるのですが、パーミッションはどのように設定するのが理想でしょうか。

この場合はsftpユーザーは1つにして共有するほうがよいのかどうかもわかりません。

Answer (score 2):

ユーザーを分ける理由にもよると思いますが、異なるUNIXユーザー間でファイルを共有する場合、次のような方法が考えられると思います。

(a). 共有用のUNIXグループを作成し、各ユーザーをそのグループに参加させる
(b). ファイルシステムのACL機能(POSIX ACL)を使用し、ユーザー単位で権限を指定する

(a)は、グループ単位でパーミッション指定する形となるため特定のユーザーのみ例外といった指定を行うことは難しいと思います。

(b)は、ユーザー単位で細かく権限を指定することが可能ですが、環境によってはパーティションの再マウントが必要になります。

また、共有対象のユーザー間であれば一律同じアクセス権を与えて構わないという場合は、
「共有用のUNIXユーザーを1つ作成、公開鍵認証を使用して、各ユーザーの公開鍵を共有用のUNIXユーザーに登録して管理する」という方法も考えられると思います。